# PHP Array function to return random integers

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am new to PHP and I am trying to create a function that generates and returns a sorted array containing 6 random numbers and then printing this. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    function getRow($ball){
        $ball = array();
        for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
            return $ball;
        }
        sort($ball);   
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(getRow(rand(1,59)));
    echo '</pre>';
```

The problem with is it I have no idea why it is printing only 1 random number from the array. Can anyone help me as to why this is or where I am going wrong, if I am going wrong?

Comment: You're `return`ing inside your `for` loop instead of setting the elements of the array.

Comment: because you are doing a return in your for loop in will return from the first iteration

Comment: The function is TERMINATED by a return!!!!

Comment: Also, you are not generating random numbers, you are generating 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I put the wrong code in, I have updated now

Comment: $ball is passed to your function as an integer and you're directly assigning an empty array to it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, there are too many issues with your original code

```
$ball = [];
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
    $ball[] = rand(1,59);
}
sort($ball); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ball);
echo '</pre>';
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 32
    [4] => 39
    [5] => 51
)
```

OR, using a function

```
function getRow()
{
    $ball = [];
    for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
        $ball[] = rand(1,59);
    }
    sort($ball); 
    return $ball;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getRow());
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I appreciate the code, but I am trying to solve this problem by using functions, not just a normal array.

Comment: Ok, try my second suggestion

Comment: Great!! Worked like a charm. I understand where I was going wrong now after understanding your method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `rand()` 6 times then sorting then returning, you can achieve your desired result without a `for` loop.

```
function getRow()
{
    $range = range(1, 59);  // generate an array containing [1,2,3,...,58,59]

   shuffle($range);  // shuffle the array

   $ball = array_slice($range, 0, 6);  // extract the first six elements

   sort($ball);  // the sort the six elements ASC

   return $ball;  // return the randomized, truncated, sorted array
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getRow());
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 16
    [3] => 26
    [4] => 32
    [5] => 52
)
```

Comment: I am trying to use a rand function my friend

Comment: Please add comments to explain what is created by each function call.  You and I know what you are doing (and I like this approach) but other readers may not follow the method.

Comment: Sorry, I got impatient and edited your answer.  Feel free to overwrite if you don't like anything.  Please remember to always explain your answers.  +1 for this answer because this is how I would probably do it (even though RiggsFolly's way may be better performing).

Answer (score 0):

Below are the points which needs to correct in your program file.

1. You are passing a single random value to the `$ball` variable. It needs to be an array with random numbers.
2. In your `for` loop, you return the value -- that means a function exit at the first iteration. So value = 1 is return and printed.
3. You need to return sorted array.

You can use this :

```
$ball = array();
function getRow($ball){
    for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
        $ball[$i] = rand(1,1000);
    }
    sort($ball);
    return $ball;
}
$sorted_array = getRow($ball);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sorted_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I am happy to see that you have included some explanation with your answer (many new posters don't do this necessary step).  I have re-formatted your code block for you.  Instead of using backticks to signify your code, you should use 4-spaces.  A quicker way is to highlight all of your code block then press `Ctrl+K` and the SO software will format your code.  Lastly, `<?php` and `?>` are not needed in your answer unless you are bouncing in and out of HTML / PHP in your answer.

Comment: Thanks mate! will take care next time.